# Enforcing order with ALAssetsLibrary enumeration blocks

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I’m doing some iterations using Apple’s ALAssetsLibrary framework. I need this iteration to finish before I start playing my videos.

Here is the reducted sample code that shows the problem I’m having.

```
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *assetsToPlay;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

    [library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
        [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
            AVAsset *asset = <#Get Asset#>
            [self.assetsToPlay addObject:asset];
        }];
    } failureBlock:nil];

    [self playem]; // BUG: This code is invoked immediately. I would like it to run only after the above block iteration finished.
}

- (void)playem
{
    for(AVAsset *asset in self.assetsToPlay) {
        NSLog(@"%@", asset);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Elad's point, the enumeration method runs asynchronously, and `group` will be `nil` when done.

So, like most asynchronous situations, you should move the call to `playem` *inside* the completion block rather than after it. You want to call `playem` when `group` is `nil` (i.e. you're done enumerating):

```
[library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
    if (group) {
        // if `group` is non-`nil`, then still enumerating the groups

        [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
            if (result) { 
                // note, only do this if `result` is not `nil` (`nil` signifies end of asset enumeration)

                AVAsset *asset = <#Get Asset#>
                [self.assetsToPlay addObject:asset];
            }
        }];
    } else {
        // if `group` is `nil`, then done with enumeration, so call method

        [self playem]; // this will be called when the enumeration is done.
    }
} failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    // handle the user's rejection of permission here
}];
```

Comment: Thank you Rob. Elad’s solution is more general, and I’ve learned from it but this solution is perfect for the current issue and thus I’ve check it.

Comment: I'll respectfully disagree with your assessment re semaphores. You almost never want to make an asynchronous method synchronous: It's more prudent to adopt the asynchronous patterns rather than fighting them. The failure to account for a single path of execution in semaphore could cause the particular thread to hang. Worse, while you generally should never do synchronous processes in the main thread, in this case it's even worse, as it will deadlock. Semaphores are powerful, but must be used judiciously. Regardless, I'm glad you got something from both answers.

Comment: Rob, thank you again for the insights. Based on your input would it be safe to assume that all of cocoa dispatch api follow a pattern of “on end dispatch” given either a completion block (as can be seen for ex on AVAssetExportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler) or here with nil object signifying the end of iteration? If so then relaying on semaphore locking does seem unnecessary in this case.

Comment: @MaximVeksler I'd personally rephrase that: Asynchronous Cocoa interfaces implement either a completion block pattern or delegate pattern to somehow indicate successful completion. And as a general rule, using semaphores to make an asynchronous method synchronous is rarely a good idea because (a) synchronous methods can make app less responsive or even be killed by watchdog process; (b) it's a little fragile; (c) if not careful, it can lock threads or completely deadlock the app. There's a reason that the API call is asynchronous, so use asynchronous programming techniques.

Comment: This use of `usingBlock` that will be be called asynchronously multiple times with `nil` to signify that it's complete is a less common pattern, but it can be considered a special case scenario of the general asynchronous pattern, namely, it's rarely prudent to try to make the asynchronous method act synchronously through the use of semaphores. Just use asynchronous programming patterns.

Answer (score 1):

'group' will become 'nil' on the last iteration, so you can use a semaphore to block the calling thread until iteration is complete:

```
- (void)syncEnumerateAssetGroups:(void(^)(ALAssetsGroup* group))block {
    NSAssert(![NSThread isMainThread], @"must not run on main thread");
    dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

    [self.library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos /*| ALAssetsGroupPhotoStream*/ usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
        if (!group) {
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
            return;
        }

        if (block) {
            block(group);
        }
    } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
        SSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error);
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
    }];

    dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
}
```

Comment: @rob thanks. Nice catch. Also, make sure this is not called from the main thread of course!

Comment: Note that `enumerateGroupsWithTypes` calls the block on the same dispatch queue which it was called in, so this code must not run on the main thread or otherwise it will go into deadlock.